# How to detect that a cell is selected but not clicked in a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cell

[image]

I have two designs for the UITableViewCells, one for the selected cells and other for the unselected cells. I can detect that a cell was selected and deselected in these events to modify their design:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But when the user tap & hold a Cell, the cell is highlighted but none of these events are activated, so I cant repaint the shadows of the UITextLabels correctly because the UITitleLabels have the method: titleLabel.highlightedTextColor but not the method titleLabel.highlightedShadowColor.

In the image:

```
1 - Unselected cell
2 - Selected cell
3 - Tap & hold cell, with ugly shadows.
```

How can I detect the user tap & hold a cell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) like this:

add the gesture to the cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *twoSecPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePress:)];
            [twoSecPress setMinimumPressDuration:2];
            [cell addGestureRecognizer: twoSecPress];
            [twoSecPress release];
```

handle the selector

```
-(void) handlePress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
 if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UITableViewCell *cellView=(UITableViewCell *)recognizer.view;
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

(Not tested).